# Package Extension for Version Upgrade

Tags: magento-1.7, extensions

I have created a extension with version `0.0.1` and it is listed on magento connect.

My question is I have to make some changes in the extension block files. After completing My Changes, I have change version number in `config xml` from `0.0.1` to `0.1.0`

there is no change in set up script, in first released it was named as `install-0.0.1.php`. do I need to rename this files as well to  `install-0.1.0.php`.

Please suggest what are the correct steps to create Version Upgrade for extension.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to rename the install. It will run `install-0.0.1`.
When installing a module Magento will run the install file with a version lower or equal to the module version. If there are 2 install scripts it will run the one closest to the version declared in `config.xml`.

Comment: To be clear: you define the "current version" of your module in the XML. When installing/updating each module, Magento will always run all install scripts named with a version number lower or equal to the "current version". So in the future when you'll add new "update" scripts to your module you'll create a new file alongside the initial install file.

Comment: @MihaiStancu. I'm not sure it will run ALL the install scripts with a version lower than the "current version". I'm 99% sure it runs only one `install` script and all the upgrade scripts between the install and current version. For example take Mage_Catalog (latest version `1.6.0.0.14`). If you install Magento 1.7 it won't run `mysql4-install-0.7.0.php`, just `install-1.6.0.0` and every `upgrade` script starting with `upgrade-1.6.0.0.1-...`.

Comment: Well there's only one install script and several upgrade scripts. If the module has never been installed on the current deployment there will be no entry for it in the `core_resouce` table so the install script will be run and the every upgrade script up to the current version.

Comment: On the other hand if the module had already been installed, there would a an entry in `core_resource` with a `version` number and all upgrade scripts with a version higher than the `core_resource.version` but lower or equal to the current version will be run.